# how to filter divs by checkbox using multiple classes

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I have a product page that fetches the products from a database table, I am using `foreach` to pull each product & each product displays as a card and using classes to filter them.

The problem is that the checkbox filter isnt working properly with multiple values (classes), if I have 2 classes the filter is only detecting the 1st class rather than all the classes(filters).

So for example, if I check the "Blue" checkbox I wont see any results since the JS is searching for a div that has only that one class ("filt-blue") but I need it to display all divs that contain "filt-blue" as well as any other filters that may be added.

See more on **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Brnd13/svuac154/49/)**

```js
function change() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  var chekboxInputs = Array.from(checkboxes).map(a => a.querySelector('input'));
  var allAreUnselected = chekboxInputs.every(function(elem) {
    return !elem.checked;
  });
  if (allAreUnselected) {
    chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input) {
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item) {
        item.style.display = 'block';
      });
    });
  } else {
    chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input) {
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item) {
        item.style.display = input.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
      });
    });
  }
}
change();
```

```css
  @media(max-width:768px){
   .card{
    width:100% !important;
    margin:12px 6px !important;
    }
  }
  .card {
  text-align:left;
  border-radius:4px;
  margin:24px;
  width:320px;
  min-height:340px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  border:var(--image-select-border);
}
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}
.card-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding:12px;
}
.card-title {
  margin-bottom:16px;
  padding:12px;
}
@media(max-width:768px){
.card-img-top{
  width:240px !important;
}
}
@media(max-width:768px){
.filtbtn{
  width:90% !important;
  margin-left:5% !important;
  float:none !important;
}
}
.filterDiv {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
@media(max-width:768px){
#opts{
  margin-left:5% !important;
}
}
.optsel{
  border-bottom:2px solid #0d6efd;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
.sidebar {
  height:100%;
  width:0;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
  top:76px;
  right:0;
  background-color:#111;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidebar a {
  padding:8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:16px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-right:12px;
  font-size:18px;
  color:#222 !important;
  background-color:#fff;
  width:100%;
}
@media(max-width:768px){
  .closebtn{
    top:4px !important;
  }
}
.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}
.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}
#main {
  transition: margin-right .5s; /* If you want a transition effect */
  padding: 20px;
}
/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 22px;}
}
.optbtn{
  background-color:#fff;
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding:14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.accordion {
  background-color:#111;
  color: #fff !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.notaccordion {
  background-color:#111;
  color: #fff !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size:18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight:bolder;
}
.active, .accordion:hover {
  opacity:0.9;
}
.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}
.filterpanel {
  padding:0 18px;
  background-color:#fff;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
.checkbox{
  color:#222 !important;
  padding:12px 12px;
}
.checkbox-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox span{
  margin-left:12px;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
.checkbox input {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 11px 23px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.checkbox-button__input {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.checkbox-button__control {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #017b5f;
    border: 2px solid #666;
}
.checkbox-button__input:checked+.checkbox-button__control:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color:#0d6efd;
}
.checkbox-button__input:checked+.checkbox-button__control {
    border-color:black;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="filter">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-button">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button__input" id="choice1-1" name="choice1" onchange="change()" rel="filt-blue">
      <span class="checkbox-button__control"></span>
    </label>
    <span><b>blue</b></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filter">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-button">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button__input" id="choice1-2" name="choice1" onchange="change()" rel="filt-red">
      <span class="checkbox-button__control"></span>
    </label>
    <span><b>red</b></span>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="filter">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-button">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button__input" id="choice1-1a" name="choice2" onchange="change()" rel="filt-long">
      <span class="checkbox-button__control"></span>
    </label>
    <span><b>long</b></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filter">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-button">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-button__input" id="choice1-2a" name="choice2" onchange="change()" rel="filt-short">
      <span class="checkbox-button__control"></span>
    </label>
    <span><b>short</b></span>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="cards">

  <div class="card filt-blue filt-long">
    <h6 class="card-title"><b><?php echo $fetch['title'];?></b></h6>
    <center><img src="/images/products/<?php echo $fetch['Img'];?>" class="card-img-top" style="width:160px;margin:0 auto;"></center>
    <div class="card-body">
      <small><?php echo $fetch['detail'];?></small>
      <h6><b>Starting from - &pound;<?php echo $fetch['SFprice'];?></b></h6>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="card filt-blue filt-short">
    <h6 class="card-title"><b><?php echo $fetch['title'];?></b></h6>
    <center><img src="/images/products/<?php echo $fetch['Img'];?>" class="card-img-top" style="width:160px;margin:0 auto;"></center>
    <div class="card-body">
      <small><?php echo $fetch['detail'];?></small>
      <h6><b>Starting from - &pound;<?php echo $fetch['SFprice'];?></b></h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @Yogi Yeah, but even on your version you can see it isn't displaying all products that are "blue" when checkbox is selected. It seems its only able to use one class at a time. When you select blue it only shows blue but it should be showing all that have the blue class including the long and short

Comment: @Yogi Also, it looks like your code is working for the "long" & "short" checkboxes, its just the first 2 (blue & red) that are having issues

Comment: @Yogi Yes, none are displayed when both columns have values, this is why I asked the question relating to fetching database values because it seems to be working very differently to what you've done, I have made the question as clear as I can, its kinda difficult to put this issue into words and not having any examples with database results makes it harder to show.

Comment: @Yogi I have updated the code but it is literally no different, the classes are still the same values, the results are still the same, I click the blue checkbox I get 1 result, you can see I have 3 divs now, they all contain "filt-blue" therefore all 3 should be shown when checking the "Blue" checkbox, but instead only 1 is being shown, test the snippet in my question, it is updated so you will see what I mean, hope its more clear

Answer (score 1):

This code should help your filter take into account multiple classes. There's a couple of ways you can filter. For example, if you have "long and blue" do you want to show ONLY long and blue? Or would you want to show a "Red Long" as well. This particular code takes into account multiple filter classes but in a logical OR fashion instead of an AND logic.

```
<body>

<label>Blue</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter-blue" onchange="change()">

<label>Red</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter-red" onchange="change()">

<label>Long</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter-long" onchange="change()">

<label>Short</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter-short" onchange="change()">

<div class="cards">
    
    <p class="filter-blue">Blue Jeans</p>
    <p class="filter-blue">Blue Cups</p>
    <p class="filter-red">Red Shirt</p>
    <p class="filter-red">Red Shirt</p>
    <p class="filter-red filter-long">Long Red Shirt</p>
    <p class="filter-red filter-short">Short Red Shirt</p>
    <p class="filter-blue filter-long">Long Blue Shirt</p>
    <p class="filter-blue filter-short">Short Blue Shirt</p>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    
function change() {

    // Step 1 - Get checked filters

    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),
        filtered = [];

    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            filtered.push(checkbox.name);
        }
    });

    // Step 2 - Show cards based on the filters
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards p');

    cards.forEach(card => {
        if (
            filtered.length === 0 || // If no filter is checked then show everything
            filtered.some(r => card.classList.contains(r)) // If the filter matches the cards class. Filter it.
        ) {
            card.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            card.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is close, but when I select "blue", "red" & "long" it displays a card that contains "filter-short"

Comment: The reason it shows short is because the card with short probably has a Red or Blue attribute. As long as ONE of the attributes in the filter match it will highlight the card. I can change the code to make it work how you want but you need to be specific on how you want the filter to work. If you're going to eliminate a card because it's missing an attribute then when you put "blue" and "red" they will all be missing because a red shirt might not have blue and vice versa. In that case I feel like the only solution is to have a more complex filtering system using categories as colors and sizes

Comment: Yes I think like you said; I'd need to have them categorized, so say for example there was color, size & fit, it would filter them normally but if a checkbox is selected where no cards have that attribute then it wont display any cards since there wont be a card that has all those attributes. So in a way it would be adding/removing them, so if I select Blue it will show all Blue and if I also select Red it will show all Blue & Red and if I also select Long it will show all that are Red, Blue and Long and if I also select Short I guess it'd just show all results, the same if none are selected

Comment: but the problem is I would also need a third one, "Fit", so 3 categories with 2-3 options for each

Answer (score 1):

##### Why doesn't the current code work?

Your code iterates over every `input`, finding all cards matching that `input`.  The first `input` is `blue`, and the code iterates over all cards and correctly displays those matching `blue`.  But it then continues to the next iteration, the `red` checkbox.  No cards match and so they are both immediately hidden.  So any matching card(s) are actually shown and then immediately hidden.

##### OK, how do we fix it?

Here's my approach:

- Since we need to evaluate all checkboxes for each indvidual card, flip the order of iteration - for each card, iterate over each checkbox (rather than the other way around as you have);
- Evaluate each checkbox: if it is checked *and* the current card has that attribute, flag it as matching, and continue checking the other checkboxes;
- But if the checkbox is checked and the current card does *not* have that attribute, flag it as a non-match.  Now we must immeidately bail out, so a future match doesn't override this failure;
- After we've checked all inputs (or bailed out on a failure), display or hide the card depending on the final state of our match;

```js
function change() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var chekboxInputs = Array.from(checkboxes).map(a => a.querySelector('input'));
    var allAreUnselected = chekboxInputs.every(function(elem) {
        return !elem.checked;
    });

    if (allAreUnselected) {
        chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input) {
            Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item) {
                item.style.display = 'block';
            });
        });

    } else {
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".card")).forEach(function(card) {
            // console.log('Start card: ', card);
            let match = false;

            for (const input of chekboxInputs) {
                let attribute = input.getAttribute("rel");
                // console.log('processing input with rel:', attribute);

                if (input.checked && card.classList.contains(attribute)) {
                    // console.log('input is checked and card matches');
                    match = true;
                    
                } else if (input.checked && ! card.classList.contains(attribute)) {
                    // console.log('input is checked and card does not match');
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // console.log('done checking inputs, match is:', match);
            card.style.display = match ? 'block' : 'none';
        });
    }
}
change();
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice1" onchange="change()" rel="filt-blue">
    <span><b>blue</b></span>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice1" onchange="change()" rel="filt-red">
    <span><b>red</b></span>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice2" onchange="change()" rel="filt-long">
    <span><b>long</b></span>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice2" onchange="change()" rel="filt-short">
    <span><b>short</b></span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="cards">
    <div class="card filt-blue filt-long">
        <b>Blue Long</b>
    </div>

    <div class="card filt-blue filt-short">
        <b>Blue Short</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

##### Notes

- It is generally considered good practice to separate your HTML and JS.  Here that would mean removing the inline `onchange="change()"` in the HTML, and replacing them with an event handler in the JS:

  ```
  let checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', change);
  ```
- You will make it so much easier for others to help if you can create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.  In this case a good chunk of the time I spent on this problem was evaulating what I could strip out - a lot of the HTML and most of the CSS classes are irrlevant.  The PHP obviously does not work, and none of the CSS matters.  Neither Bootstrap nor jQuery CSS or JS refs are necessary.
  When you strip out everything not related to the problem it is that much easier to understand, debug, and work with.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I think this is close to what I need it to do, but is it possible to make it so that if red & blue are checked it will show all cards that contain "red" & "blue" and also if "red", "blue" & "long" is checked it will show all cards that contain "red", "blue" & "long"? I tried on JSFiddle here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Brnd13/pvzwbro9/6/)

Comment: Do you mean the checkboxes should act like OR instead of AND?  So if red and blue are checked, it will show all cards that contain either red or blue?